# Concatenated all the <p> tags using u' '.join in scrapy but unable to export that particular columns to a csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, export-to-csv

This is a piece of code and the entire concatenated text field is not seen in the csv file instead the first letter is seen. Also the name field is returned perfectly.

Q: Does this have something to do with settings.py file where we can mention/specify settings related to particular spider? Because if a particular text element of a particular class is extracted then the text field is filled in the csv file.

Using Scrapy version: 1.4.0 on a Macbook Pro

```
def parse(self, response):
    #text
    text = u''.join(response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "tab-")]//p//text()').extract())
    #name
    names = response.css('div.inner.html-content h1::text').extract()
```

Comment: How are you returning those fields?, are you using a `TakeFirst` processor?, because names would be receiving a list while text is receiving a string (the first element in both cases is the header's text and the first letter.

Comment: No processor was used. But just a loop to append all the items corresponding to one row and then yielding them. To reiterate, name was extracted fine, the issue is only with text field.

Comment: I think I would need to see more code to be able to help you, just for testing could you try to assign text to a list something like `text = [u''.join(...)]`